# Java and SQL query: slowness

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xampp

I'm getting a java applet to populate a database.

I work with JDK 1.7 and XAMPP 3.2.1 32Bit on a HP i3 ram6gb. 
My database is big and have this structure:

```
[TABLE] attributi   rows:245    InnoDB  16 KiB
[TABLE]dati         rows:1,938,620  InnoDB  167.7 MiB
[TABLE]minilinks    rows:12,670,740 InnoDB  625 MiB
[TABLE]personaggi   rows:196,046    InnoDB  8.5 MiB
[TABLE]relazioni    rows:0      InnoDB  16 KiB
```

I have to fill table 'relazioni'. This is the code:

```
public class PageLink {

private static  boolean  cleanRelazioni = true;
private static  boolean  relazioni = true;

static public void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {    

     String intestazione =  "################################# Progetto Parser/Scanner XML Wikipedia #############################################################\n\n";
     System.out.println(intestazione);
     PrintWriter outRel = null;

     //connessione al Database
     Database db = new Database("wikipages","","root","localhost");
     if(db.connect()){
            System.out.println("Connessione al Database ESEGUITA.");                
     }
     if(cleanRelazioni){
         db.cleanRelazioni();
     }

     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

     if(relazioni){
         int cont = 0;
         System.out.println("Relazioni delle sole Biografie");
         outRel = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fileTest/outputRelazioniPageToPage.txt"));

         try{
             outRel.println("Relazioni delle sole Biografie");
         }
         catch(Exception e){        
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

             //tiro fuori Nome+Cognome corrente             
             List<Integer> listaPersonaggi = db.getIDPersonaggi();
             for (int id : listaPersonaggi) {   
                System.out.println("\nIl Personaggio ");
                db.printPersonaggio(id);
                System.out.println("E' correlato con ");
                cont = db.checkPageToPage(id);                      
                System.out.println("=====>"+cont+"\n\n");

                try{    
                    outRel.flush();
                    outRel.println(id + " è correlato con "+cont+" personaggi.");
                    outRel.println("");
                 }
                 catch(Exception e){        
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
     }


     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Tempo Esecuzione: " + (endTime - startTime) + " millisecondi => secondi "+(endTime - startTime)/1000);
     System.out.println("FINE PROGRAMMA.");
     db.disconnect();        
   }
}
```

this are the the method of the Database's Class:

```
public int checkPageToPage(int id){
 List<Integer> listaPersonaggiCorrelati = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 listaPersonaggiCorrelati.add(id);

 Statement stmt;
 ResultSet rs;
 String query = null;
 int conteggio = 0;
 String personaggio = new String("");

try {
     stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
     query = "SELECT pl_title FROM minilinks WHERE pl_from="+id+"";
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
     while (rs.next()) {
         personaggio = rs.getString("pl_title").replace("_", " ").replace("\"", "");             
         if(checkExistPersonaggio(personaggio)!=-1){
             listaPersonaggiCorrelati.add(checkExistPersonaggio(personaggio));
             System.out.print("personaggio correlato => "+personaggio+"\n");
             conteggio++;
         }
     }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}    
if (conteggio>0)
    insertRelazioni (listaPersonaggiCorrelati);
return conteggio;
}


public void insertRelazioni(List<Integer> listaPersonaggiCorrelati){

int id_personaggio1;
int id_personaggio2;
try {       
    for(int i=0; i<=listaPersonaggiCorrelati.size()-1;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=listaPersonaggiCorrelati.size()-1;j++){
            int tot_relazioni=0;
            id_personaggio1=listaPersonaggiCorrelati.get(i);
            id_personaggio2=listaPersonaggiCorrelati.get(j);
            if(id_personaggio1 != id_personaggio2){                     
                    //System.out.println(id_personaggio1+" e "+id_personaggio2);
                    tot_relazioni=checkExistRelazione(id_personaggio1, id_personaggio2);
                    if (tot_relazioni==-1){
                        //System.out.println("nuova relazione tra "+id_personaggio1+" e "+id_personaggio2);
                        executeUpdate("INSERT into relazioni (id_personaggio, id_personaggio_correlato, tot) VALUES("+id_personaggio1+", "+id_personaggio2+", '1')");  
                    }
                        else {
                            //System.out.println("aggiorno la relazione tra "+id_personaggio1+" e "+id_personaggio2);
                            tot_relazioni++;
                            executeUpdate("UPDATE relazioni SET tot="+tot_relazioni+" WHERE id_personaggio = "+id_personaggio1+" and id_personaggio_correlato = "+id_personaggio2+"");  
                        }
            }
        }
    }

   } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      e.getMessage(); 
    }   
}
```

My problem is: insert query are very very slow.. for insert 4000 rows this takes 30minutes.
Is there anything I can do to fix this problem? I'm curious of what this cause mean and why I'm having trouble.
Maybe I can use Mysql 64bit version?

Comment: First try to use PreparedStatement, second try to use a pool like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), third use transactions.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I will try with c3p0. But how can i modify my applet for use the transactions?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

Since miniliks is the biggest table and you select

> "SELECT pl_title FROM minilinks WHERE pl_from="+id+"";

Do have a special index on pl_from column?

Comment: No, table minilinks have the structure:

pl_from    int(8)       ----   
pl_title   varbinary(255)   

Do i have to add index?
I think that the problem (maybe) is in the method insertRelazioni()

Comment: Well you have your answer above in The Otter comment. The Index will help for The select

Comment: I added index but i haven't resolved the problem. Instead the problem will come when the method insertRelazioni() in the for cicle tries to insert records.